# How to deploy two war files onto Jboss 6.4.0

Tags: server, jboss

I have two war files `msg-producer` and `msg-consumer`. How to deploy these two war files onto `jboss 6.4.0` simultaneously?

currently deploying one war file like this:

1. copy war file into EAP\standalone\deployments folder
2. Run standalone.bat from EAP-6.4.0\bin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy two or multiple WAR files into EAP\standalone\deployments folder.

Each web application will have a different context root, using context root you can access the application.

Comment: Ok, Can you provide some link or steps, how to create different context root for each web application and run wars simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can deploy two or more WAR/EAR files in the JBoss Application server.

Please go through the $JBOSS_ROOT/standalone/deployments/README.txt

There are two different modes 1. auto-deploy mode and 2. manual deploy mode

1. Manual deployment relies on a system of marker
   files, with the user's addition or removal of a marker file serving as a sort
   of command telling the scanner to deploy, undeploy or redeploy content.
2. Auto-deploy mode: The scanner will directly monitor the deployment content,
   automatically deploying new content and redeploying content whose timestamp
   has changed.

Read the README.txt for more details.

The simplest way I recommend is

1. Login the JBoss admin console
2. Under deployments tab, click on "add" and select the required msg-producer and msg-consumer war files. "Enable" checkbox to be selected.
3. Access the application http://localhost(or_servername):8080/contextroot/